# Complex FormatCondition in excel c# interop

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I've big difficulties to translate an excel format condition formula.

I have several rows with this columns structure :

the easy part :

[A] [B] [C] [D]

A : V1
B : V3
C : =|V1 - V3|
D : Vr

the hard part is the formula itself. the only way to describe is to write like that :

```
if(|vr| =< 160)
{
   if(|V1-V3| =< 2%|V1| + 1)
    {
         cellbackground = red;
    }
}
else
{
   if(|V1-V3| =< 1%|V1|)
   {
        cellbackground = red;
   }
}
```

Can someone help me ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution is :

```
 FormatCondition cond = theRange.FormatConditions.Add( XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "=SI(ABS(VR) =< 160; ABS(V1 - V3) =< (0.02*ABS(V1) + 1; ABS(V1 - VR) =< (0.01 * ABS(V1)) )", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing );
 
 cond.Font.Color = Color.Red.ToOle();
 cond.Font.Bold = true;
```

F.